# vuejs component hides everything after if not put inside a div

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, parceljs

I started using vuejs with parcel. I have a main component App.vue from which I call a subcomponent Hello.vue using `<Hello/>` in App's template. I have a weird bug if I don't put the `<Hello/>` inside a div tag, everything that comes after in html doesn't show. The code is below:

index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <h3>bla bla</h3>

    <div><Hello/></div>
    <!-- if not put inside a div, hides everything after-->

    <h2>test</h2>
    <p>kldsfnlkdsjfldsfds</p>
    <h5>skjdnsqkfdnlkdsqf</h5>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hello from "./components/Hello";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Hello
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Hello.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
    <h2>Hello {{ person.firstname}} {{person.lastname}}</h2>
    <label>
      Firstname:
      <input type="text" v-model="person.firstname">
    </label>
    <label>
      Lastname:
      <input type="text" v-model="person.lastname">
    </label>
    <label>
      Message:
      <input type="text" v-model="message">
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      person: {
        firstname: "John",
        lastname: "Doe"
      },
      message: "Welcome !"
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Here is a screenshot of what I get without wrapping `<Hello/>` with a `<div></div>`
[image: without a div]
And then with a div:
[image: with a div]

Thanks !

EDIT: I don't get an error in the console. I forgot to add that I tried with webpack and I don't get this bug, so It's most likely related to parcel.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: No I don't get an error in the console. I forgot to add that I tried with webpack and I don't get this bug, so It's most likely related to parcel.

Comment: Did you try <Hello></Hello> without surrounding divs?

Comment: Also, post the generated code so we can see if your component is missing from the DOM, or if it is hidden by CSS settings.

Comment: Thanks @StevenSpungin that worked. Do you have the explanation why the two syntaxes are possible ? and why does ```<Hello/>``` works well when using webpack but is problematic with parcel ?

Comment: @AmineSOUIKI I put an explanation in the solution below.  Did your source have the element BTW?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some browsers do not display elements correctly if they use `<foo />` without a closing tag, instead of `<foo></foo>`.

If items are not rendered with the closing tag, this may be your issue.

Some `vue` components will generate the closing tag from your template, even though you do not have it in your source, and others will not.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a SFC (Single File Component) you **must have only one element inside the `<template>`**. Then, inside that one element you can have as many other elements as you like.

Have a look at the *"Example sandbox"* **Simple to do app** in the official documentation: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html#Example-Sandbox

The file `ToDoList.vue` is a good example in here: https://codesandbox.io/s/o29j95wx9

Comment: Actually that's not the problem. I think I wasn't accurate enough, I am not refering to the div the wraps the whole App.vue (which has id=app). But I have to do this to not have the bug : ```<div><Hello /></div>``` inside the ```<div id="app> </div>```